# Field errors not displayed Flask

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to return custom error messages on my forms, but for some reason the error doesn't show up on the form when it is reloaded. I am guessing that the field.error object is empty, but I don't know why.

The way I return the error is just like in the documentation.

```
    def validate_email(self, email):
        user = models.User.query.filter_by(email=email.data).first()

        if user is None:
            raise ValidationError('Such user not found')
```

This is my render_template macro:

```
{% macro render_field(field) %}
    {{ field.label }}

    {{ field }}

    {% if field.errors %}
        <ul>
            {% for error in field.errors %}
                <li>{{ error }}</li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    {% endif %}
{% endmacro %}
```

Comment: That just means there are no errors.  What makes you think that there should be any errors?

Comment: Because when I teied logging im on purpose with a non existing email, the form did not validate but the error did not appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was in how I re-rendered the template, I was using the forms class, instead of the specific form object that was just used.

```
return render_template(self.template_name, title=self.title, form=form_class())
```

Solution

```
return render_template(self.template_name, title=self.title, form=form)
```

Edit, but that didn't fix an issue of my custom exception LoginError not being counted as a field error